# Django slow server response with large file upload

Tags: python, django

Python 3.6 and Django 1.11

I am sending from a client `multipart/form-data` to a Django form, the model looks like

```
class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')
```

and I am using class based views

```
class DocumentCreate(CreateView):
    model = Document
    form_class = DocumentForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('document_list')
```

and a classic ModelForm:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = '__all__'
```

I'm on the embedded server, which I know may perform poorly, but when I send a `2gb` files with the client, is see that the file is created after ~10 seconds (and databases entries etc..) but the client have to wait 10 more seconds for the Django server to send the response (seen with Wireshark).

I can even `keyboardinterupt` the client script before the Django server answer, with no consequences to the data transmission.

Here is the client script in gross:

```
fich = open('2go', 'rb')

sess = requests.session()

data = {'author': 'gerard',
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken,
        'name': 'gerard'}
sess.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/post_document', data=data, files{'file': fich})
```

I got another script which streams the multipart data, but its slower and also have to wait for the server response.

So the question is, why is the server answer so slow, although everything is already uploaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From docs, [Where uploaded data is stored](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/#where-uploaded-data-is-stored)

> if an uploaded file is too large, Django will write the uploaded file to a temporary file stored in your system’s temporary directory. On a Unix-like platform this means you can expect Django to generate a file called something like /tmp/tmpzfp6I6.upload. If an upload is large enough, you can watch this file grow in size as Django streams the data onto disk.

From docs, [Handling uploaded files with a model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model)

> The file object will be saved to the location specified by the upload_to argument of the corresponding FileField when calling form.save()

From source code, [Storage save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/core/files/storage/#Storage.save):

```
            # This file has a file path that we can move.
            if hasattr(content, 'temporary_file_path'):
                file_move_safe(content.temporary_file_path(), full_path)
```

Conclusion: It seems your system take for long to "move" file from temp to final place. Check if your temporary location in the same partition than final store location to move fast your file instead to make a copy of it. May be you need to tune your [TemporaryFileUploadHandler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/#upload-handlers)

Comment: I don't think so, because i see the file in its final location, with the correct size and hash. The problem is, while the file is fully uploaded, the server doesn't send immediately a response to the client, like `201 created`. Thus, the client is waiting the response for like 10 more seconds. But i will take a look to file upload handlers

Comment: Also you see the file deleted from temporary place?

Comment: Ok, youre right ! The file goes to its final destination, everything is ok, but django wait until the file is deleted from the tmp dir to send the 201 code. Which is a bit of problem for me in terms of performance

Comment: I guess this is not the issue. Is not a slow delete. I guess django is still copying file. May be all space allocated ( it seems file is there ) but not content.

Comment: Yea, exactly, when i killed the django server right after the apparition of the file in the final dir, the file was incomplete.

Comment: But still, django has received all the amount of data, and should transmit the http code, the client haven't to wait django for cleaning its mess

Comment: Yes and Not. If django says ok and server crash, file was not moved to final storage and data will be lost because nobody knows about it. If this is not an issue for you, just move the file asynchronously. Best regards man. Au revoir :)